# Wpf.PropertyGrid ComboBox from String Array in Custom Attribute

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, wpf-controls, propertygrid

Suppose I have the following custom attribute decorated class that implements a TypeConverter. I would like to create a combobox in the Wpf.PropertyGrid such that the values in the combobox are taken from the string array specified in the custom attribute. The issue I am having is that although I can iterate through all the properties with the custom attribute, I cannot figure out the actual property that invoked the TypeConverter as the context.PropertyGrid is null. Can such a combobox be created? If yes, how?

The class:

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]
public class Animals : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // Constructor
    public Animals()
    {
        foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this))
        {
            DefaultValueAttribute attr = (DefaultValueAttribute)prop.Attributes[typeof(DefaultValueAttribute)];
            if (attr != null)
                prop.SetValue(this, attr.Value);
        }
    }

    // Properties
    private string _pets, _others;

    // both properties have the same TypeConverter, but they use different custom attributes
    [RefreshProperties(RefreshProperties.All)]
    [TypeConverter(typeof(ListTypeConverter))]
    [ListTypeConverterAttribute(new [] { "cat", "dog" })]
    [ListTypeConverterAttribute(new [] { "cat1", "dog1" })]
    [DefaultValue("cat")]
    public string Pets
    {
        get { return _pets; }
        set { SetField(ref _pets, value); }
    }

    [RefreshProperties(RefreshProperties.All)]
    [ListTypeConverterAttribute(typeof(ListTypeConverter))]
    [ListTypeConverterAttribute(new [] { "cow", "sheep" })]
    [DefaultValue("sheep")]
    public string Others
    {
        get { return _others; }
        set { SetField(ref _others, value); }
    }

    // Methods
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }

    // ----- Implement INotifyPropertyChanged -----
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    protected bool SetField<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value))
            return false;
        field = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }
}
```

The custom attribute:

```
public sealed class ListTypeConverterAttribute : Attribute
{
    public ListTypeConverterAttribute(params string[] list)
    {
        this.List = list;
    }

    public string[] List { get; set; }

    public override object TypeId
    {
        get { return this; }
    }
}
```

The TypeConverter:

```
public class ListTypeConverter : TypeConverter
{
    public override bool GetStandardValuesSupported(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override bool GetStandardValuesExclusive(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override StandardValuesCollection GetStandardValues(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        base.GetStandardValues(context);

        List<string> list = new List<string>();

        // HERE IS MY ISSUE ...
        // How do I get the property invoking the TypeConverter so I can get its list?
        // context.PropertyGrid == null

        return new StandardValuesCollection(list);
    }
}
```

Comment: From which UI kit is the property grid from, Xceed, Syncfusion ...?

Comment: The grid is from WPF PropertyGrid control by Denis Vuyka; https://github.com/DenisVuyka/WPG; https://github.com/DenisVuyka/WPG/tree/master/Samples

Comment: your code doesn't even compile with last build: duplicate `ListTypeConverter` attributes

Comment: @Aybe: Good catch. Missed a line of code for the Attribute class: [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = true)]  My code has this and compiles fine.

Comment: Consider adding a complete, working example, see, I opened the repo in VS, pasted your code, then figured out that a bunch of stuff is missing for a repro ... i.e. maximize your chances of getting an answer.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you are referring to. The code posted is the key part, and it works except for the part indicated in the TypeConverter. If I knew the property invoking/calling the TypeConverter I could easily get the TypeConverter working. You can use StackTrace to get the current method, but I don't know the equivalent to get the current property/member.

Comment: What I'm saying is that nobody is going to bother coding all you didn't post to make a complete example that can be ran. As I said, maximize your chances to get an answer by improving your question!